# Cordova Camera access crash app on Nexus 7 with Android 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Using Cordova 6.3.1, I installed the following Crodova plugins:
cordova-plugin-camera, cordova.plugins.diagnostic, phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

I'm using the following JavaScript code to access the Camera and scan a QR code:

```
function scanQR() {
    cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization(function(status) {
        console.log("Authorization request for camera returned " + status);
        if (status == cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED) {
            try {
                cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(scanQRDone, function (error)   {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.message);
            }
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function scanQRDone(result) {
    console.log(result);
}
```

The requestCameraAuthorization call prompts for a confirmation on the device and when allowed returns status GRANTED.
However the call to cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan simply crashes the application on the Nexus 7.

The actual line in which the crash occurs is cordova.js line 940:

```
var msgs = nativeApiProvider.get().exec(bridgeSecret, service, action, callbackId, argsJson);
```

Where service="BarcodeScanner" and action="scan"
Seems like some kind of version mismatch in native code, any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new ionic application from scratch and copying the content of the www folder into it has resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the file config.xml add this

```
< platform name="android" > <br>
    < preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" /> <br>
< /platform>
```